# Using ng-token-auth submitLogin method to a different url

Tags: angularjs, devise, ionic-framework, rails-api

I am using [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth) with angular/ionic that connects to a rails api.  I am currently working on the login page.  I have the following form in the code:

```
<form ng-submit="submitLogin(loginForm)" role="form" ng-init="loginForm = {}">
    <input type="email"
         name="email"
         id="email"
         placeholder="Email"
         ng-model="loginForm.email"
         required="required" />

    <input type="password"
         name="password"
         id="password"
         placeholder="Password"
         ng-model="loginForm.password"
         required="required" />

    <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

The submitLogin function succesfully sends a post request to:

```
POST http://localhost:8100/api/auth/sign_in
```

The problem is that this is on the ionic server.  The rails app is located at `localhost:3000`.  How do I get the post request to go to that URL.  Since almost every single angular api ever created will be sending requests to a different server, I have to imagine this is included somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change default apiUrl in your app.js file (or whatever you called it) using .config

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ng-token-auth'])
.config(function($authProvider) {
    $authProvider.configure({
      apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000'
    });
});
```

Here is the link to all possible configuration options for
[ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth#configuration)

Comment: Thank you BigHeart